# What fraction of all possible configurations would meet the criteria?

Tags: probability

The problem is put as follows:

> Ada, Bella, Colette, and Delia are about to stand in a row, and Bella and Colette want to stand next to each other. What fraction of all possible configurations would satisfy their wish?

[image]

[image]

BCxx, xBCx, and xxBC, three in total, are the only acceptable arrangements. The total number of arrangements is 4 * 3 * 2 * 1=24. 3/24=1/8. I submitted it, but Brilliant says it's actually 1/2. Why?

UPD: The total number of desirable arrangements is not 3 but 3 * 2 (because CB is also fine) * 2 (because, for example, BCxx is actually not one but two arrangements, BCDA and BCAD) = 12. 12/24=1/2. Thanks, @lulu

Comment: What's wrong with, say, $CBxx$?  Note, too, that there are $2$ ways to populate the $xx$ in such an expression.  That is $CBAD$ and $CBDA$ are both valid.

Comment: @lulu I guess the way it was phrased made me think that it can only be BC

Comment: But even so, you dropped a factor of $2$.  As to the interpretation, I think "next to each other" clearly means either $BC$ or $CB$.  In any case, that interpretation matches the official result.

Comment: @lulu ok, I get it now. I undercounted desirable outcomes

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are $6$ pairs of people (AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD). In any line up, there are three pairs of adjacent people. (For instance if the line up is DCAB, then CD, AC, AB are adjacent.) So in any line up three of six possible adjacencies occur. So the probability of any given adjacency is $\frac36=\frac12$.

Comment: What about BA, CA, etc.? Then it's gonna be 3/12, isn't it?

Comment: The pairs are unordered. Either you stand next to someone or you don't.